# Union Operator in Pinot

Tags: sql, apache-pinot

I've looked into Apache Pinot's documentation and can't find any evidence of the existance of an UNION operator. I've tried doing the following in Pinot's Query Console:

```sql
select column_1
from table_1 
UNION
select column_1
from table_1
```

but got this error:

```
ProcessingException(errorCode:150, message:SQLParsingError:
java.lang.ClassCastException: class org.apache.calcite.sql.SqlBasicCall cannot be cast to class org.apache.calcite.sql.SqlSelect (org.apache.calcite.sql.SqlBasicCall and org.apache.calcite.sql.SqlSelect are in unnamed module of loader 'app')
    at org.apache.pinot.sql.parsers.CalciteSqlParser.compileSqlNodeToPinotQuery(CalciteSqlParser.java:396)
    at org.apache.pinot.controller.api.resources.PinotQueryResource.getQueryResponse(PinotQueryResource.java:185)
    at org.apache.pinot.controller.api.resources.PinotQueryResource.executeSqlQuery(PinotQueryResource.java:139)
    at org.apache.pinot.controller.api.resources.PinotQueryResource.handlePostSql(PinotQueryResource.java:103))
```

Does anyone know if the UNION operator exists and I'm just using it wrong? In case it doesn't exist, how can I achieve the desired result?

Comment: try to nest it
`select column from ( .. union ..)`

Comment: Why would you union the same column from the same table? Assuming you are querying different tables, are the columns of the same type?

Comment: @Isolated I used that as an example. In reality I'm not using the same data but I used this example so the columns would be the same type.

Comment: @merof I tried this as per your sugestion:
```select column_1 from (
  select column_1
  from table_1 
  UNION
  select column_1
  from table_1
)```
but is has returned another error:
```ProcessingException(errorCode:450, message:InternalError:
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid path string "/CONFIGS/TABLE/SELECT `column_1`
FROM `table_1`
UNION
SELECT `column_1`
FROM `table_1`_OFFLINE" caused by invalid charater @40)```
(btw, of course these are not the names of the columns and tables, it's just for example)